# Why am I unable to create additional keys in this nested dictionary?

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a SQL table with the following Columns: Firm, Product, Alias.

**I need to create a data set out of this table using only one SQL Execute Query.**

Firm column has duplicates, I only need one dictionary for each firm. Each firm has it's own products--each Product within a Firm dictionary needs it's own dictionary. Each  firm and product combination has it's own Alias. The Alias should sit inside of a list in the deepest level Dictionary: Firm Dict>Product Dict>Alias List

```py
def test():
    d = {}
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

    cursor.execute('SELECT FirmName, InfoSysName, Alias, WhereAmI_UserId FROM WhereAmIFirmInfoSysMapping_v')
    for row in cursor:
        if row['FirmName'] != '*':
            d[row['FirmName']] = {}
            d[row['FirmName']][row['InfoSysName']] = []

    print d

    conn.close()
```

**I am able to return a dictionary that looks like so:**

```
{u'FirmA': {u'ProductZ': []}, {u'FirmB': {u'ProductZ': []}, {u'FirmA': {u'ProductZ': []}
```

**However, you can see that only the last Product from my SQL table gets added to the Firm dictionary. I need to be able to add all of the Products the Firm has in the SQL table, and only those products which the Firm has.**

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting the dictionary you create. You need to change your structure slightly and add code to first check whether the firm was already added to the dictionary:

```
def test():
    d = {}
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

    cursor.execute('SELECT FirmName, InfoSysName, Alias, WhereAmI_UserId FROM WhereAmIFirmInfoSysMapping_v')
    for row in cursor:
        if row['FirmName'] != '*':
            if row['FirmName'] not in d:
                d[row['FirmName']] = {}
            d[row['FirmName']][row['InfoSysName']] = []

    print d

    conn.close()
```